# What is the difference between "Ms." and "Mrs."?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "[**Ms.**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ms?q=MS.)" and "[**Mrs.**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mrs?q=MRS)"?

I always assumed they are the same, until today I found both of them in one place for choice, seems that there's a difference between them:

N.b. I couldn't find a difference on the dictionary (see links to the words).

[image]

Comment: The difference is right there in your citations:  Ms: used to avoid saying if she is married or not.  Mrs: used before the name of a married woman.  The remaining common option is Miss (with no period): used for an *un*married woman.

Comment: I wouldn't call it duplicate, since the other questions don't deal with the difference, but they ask if one of the options is interchangeable.

Comment: I'm more than happy to make sure that you get and understand the answer you need, Judicious, but as it stands it is an off-topic question.  You could have gotten a complete and useful answer simply by typing your question directly into a search engine like Google.